# Insert digits into input field with JS keypad without erasing previously entered digits

Tags: javascript

Looking for some help with a project I am working on, guys and gals.

I have a simple keypad with the digits from 0 to 9, each one is a separate element.

My goal is to bind onclick() events on all of the elements, and make them insert the respective digit into an input field of my choosing.

I know how to set the value of a certain element ( in this case the input field ), but I don't know how to preserve the previously entered digits without rewriting the value of the entire field with the next clicked digit on the keypad.

```
document.getElementById("field").value = "digit-here"
```

This is how I set the whole value field. How do I insert a digit without erasing the previously entered ones?

Comment: looks like how you erase the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with the following:

```
document.getElementById("field").value += "digit-here"
```

Basically just add **+** before the equal sign (=).

Answer (score 1):

Get the existing value, add the digit to the end, set that value. `+=` is happy to do that for you with `value`:

```js
function handler(e) {
  document.getElementById("field").value += this.value;
}

for (let n = 1; n < 10; ++n) {
  const btn = document.createElement("input");
  btn.type = "button";
  btn.value = n;
  btn.addEventListener("click", handler);
  document.body.appendChild(btn);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="field">
<br>
```

Doing that when the text field had focus might be problematic because the insertion point would get moved, but since clicking the button will make the text field lose focus anyway, that's not an issue in this simple situation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out as @T.J Crowder said

```
var text = document.getElementById("field").value = "";

text.value += '';
```